# I look for an option to give the readed JSON file out in a textbox or an Listview

Tags: c#, json, serialization

This is my code I use to read an JSON File and try to put th readed file into a Textbox or a ListView.
For example: I want to see the JSON File as a String in a Textbox or in a Listview.
Is there anyone that can held me at this problem?
I think ther is something to do with serialization or deserialization

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace TRG_2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // pick the current User and show it in the Textbox
            string username =     System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            TxtUser.Text = username;
        }

        private void BtnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Browse the Filesystem and open the selected File in the Textbox
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.DefaultExt = ".json";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                String Filename = ofd.FileName;
                TxtFile.Text = Filename;


                StreamReader Test = new StreamReader(Filename);
                JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(Test);


                int counterRead = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    counterRead++;
                    string JSONObject = Filename;
                    var TestResult1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Testdefinition>>(JSONObject);


            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

That is my JSON sample.

```
{
    "TestID":"1",
    "TestVersion":"1.0",
    "TestGroup":"Group1",
    "TestName":"Sample-Test",
    "TestDescription":
        "1.Appl.starten(Applikation ist gestartet) 2.Datei laden(Datei     ist geladen und wird angezeigt) 3.Datei Ă¤ndern 4.Datei speichern"
}
```

The class is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace TRG_2
{
    public class Testdefinition
    { 
        public int TestID { get; set; }
        public double TestVersion { get; set; }
        public string TestGroup { get; set; }
        public string TestName { get; set; }
        public string TestDescription { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }      
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with the code? what have you achieved so far?

Comment: I have a Json File , that must be read and tak it into the textbox or the listview.
That is the JSON File:
{
"TestID":"1",
"TestVersion":"1.0",
"TestGroup":"Group1",
"TestName":"Sample-Test",
"TestDescription":"1.Appl.starten(Applikation ist gestartet) 2.Datei laden(Datei ist geladen und wird angezeigt) 3.Datei Ă¤ndern 4.Datei speichern"
}
I like to put in a listbox or textbox in a excel styl. with columns and rows inluded the headers

Comment: you are kinda in the right way, you have to make this json file into a single string variable, after that you can use the DeserializeObject object, don't try to deserialize the file name string.

Comment: Sorry but i have no idea how to make this like you tell me in your post. I have no clue at the moment, feels like a little bit brain offline

Comment: I made an answer for you with right path

Comment: Use the [edit] button under your question to add information to your question. The Answer box is for answer , not for additional information.

Comment: The Json is not a `List<Testdefinition>` but a simple `Testdefinition`. In Json  [specification](https://www.json.org/), array/list use `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the JSON File as a string

```
var pathToJson = "Path of Jason | FileName";
var r = new StreamReader(pathToJson);
var myJson = r.ReadToEnd();
```

After that with the string you can serialize the object

```
var TestResult1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Testdefinition>>(myJson );
```

With the object you can create anything you want

Or you can do it directly

```
var TestResult1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Testdefinition>>(File.ReadAllText("Path of Json"));
```

Comment: I try it that way and i got the following errormessage:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TRG_2.Testdefinition]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'TestID', line 2, position 9.'

Comment: it is your json format, try to change DeserializeObject<List<Testdefinition>> to DeserializeObject<Testdefinition[]>

Comment: you can put in the question a sample of your json and how is your class of deseralization to make it easier

Comment: My Testdefinition Class is :
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
     namespace TRG_2
     {
         public class Testdefinition
         {
             public int TestID { get; set; }
             public double TestVersion { get; set; }
             public string TestGroup { get; set; }
             public string TestName { get; set; }
             public string TestDescription { get; set; }
             public string Result { get; set; }
             public string Comment { get; set; }
        }       
     }

Comment: are u sure that your json is a list of itens? try to  DeserializeObject<Testdefinition> or the other way i said  DeserializeObject<Testdefinition[]>